# How to parse html tags hierarchy in python?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have a html page where I am extracting all the headers (`h1` to `h7`) using beautiful soup and now I want a list where I want to append all the immediate higher level tags to the current tag.

For eg, I have this sample html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>dummy h1</h1>
<h1>head 1</h1>
<p>para 1</p>
<h2>head 2</h2>
<p>para 2</p>
<h3>head 3</h3>
<p>p for head3</p>
<h2>head2(2)</h2>
<p>para3</p>
<h1>head1(2)</h1>
<h2>2nd h2</h2>
<h3>2nd h3</h3>
<p>2nd p for h3</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here the list I want should look like

```
['head1','head1 head2','head1 head2 head3','head1 head2(2)','head1(2)','head1(2) 2nd h2','head1(2) 2nd h2 2nd h3']
```

The logic I am using is breaking the loop as soon as I encounter a smaller h tag while traversing backwards from the current h tag. This is creating a problem because the loop is breaking at `head3` while traversing back from `head2(2)` where it should ideally go upto `head1`. Here is the code I tried:

```
file = open("sample.html","r")
page = file.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
tags=['h1','h2','h3','h4','h5','h6','h7']
start=soup.find('h1') # the page I am working on starts with a dummy

head=[]
h=[]
h3=[]     

for ele in start.next_siblings:
    for i,tag in enumerate(tags):
        if (ele.name==tag):
            head.append('')
            h.append(ele)
            h3=deepcopy(h)
            h3.reverse()
            for j, q in enumerate(h3):
                if q.name in tags[:i]:
                    head[len(head)-1]=(q.text.strip()) + ' ' + head[len(head)-1]

                if j < len(h)-1 and (tags.index(q.name) == tags.index(h3[j+1].name)):
                    continue

                if j < len(h)-1 and (tags.index(q.name) < tags.index(h3[j+1].name)):
                    break

            head[len(head)-1]+=(ele.text.strip())+' '
            break
print(head)
```

Please suggest what can I do to avoid this problem.

Comment: I don't understand your expected list. Is it a list of tag names or a list of tag values?

Comment: I want a list of tag values. Please refer to the example if the wording of the question is unclear.

Comment: It's still unclear; you should change your sample HTML to be clearer; for example, `<h1>h1</h1>` should be `<h1>Some h1 text</h1>`, etc. and then redo your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was wrong with your algorithm. You just need to do a test on the value of `q.name` in your `break` condition

```
if j < len(h)-1 and (tags.index(q.name) < tags.index(h3[j+1].name)) and q.name == 'h1':
    break
```

So the full code will be:

```
file = open("sample.html","r")
page = file.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
tags=['h1','h2','h3','h4','h5','h6','h7']
start=soup.find('h1') # the page I am working on starts with a dummy

head=[]
h=[]
h3=[]

for ele in start.next_siblings:
    for i,tag in enumerate(tags):
        if (ele.name==tag):
            head.append('')
            h.append(ele)
            h3=deepcopy(h)
            h3.reverse()
            for j, q in enumerate(h3):

                if q.name in tags[:i]:
                    head[len(head)-1]=(q.text.strip()) + ' ' + head[len(head)-1]

                if j < len(h)-1 and (tags.index(q.name) == tags.index(h3[j+1].name)):
                    continue

                if j < len(h)-1 and (tags.index(q.name) < tags.index(h3[j+1].name)) and q.name == 'h1':
                    break

            head[len(head)-1]+=(ele.text.strip())+' '
            break
print(head)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
['head 1 ', 'head 1 head 2 ', 'head 1 head 2 head 3 ', 'head 1 head2(2) ', 'head1(2) ', 'head1(2) 2nd h2 ', 'head1(2) 2nd h2 2nd h3 ']
```

Let me know if it helps :-)